# How to send nested form-data using postman?

Tags: django, postman

Assume I have some data as below,

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars": 
    {
        "car_img_1":"car_img_file1",
        "car_img_2":"car_img_file2",
        "car_img_3":"car_img_file3"
    }
 }
```

How can I send it using `POSTMAN` with `form-data`?

**NOTES**
1. `car_img_fileX` will be the file(`.jpg`,`.png` etc types)
2. What I'd tried -->> [POSTMAN Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phzpq.jpg). 
3. Local server builted with Django framework

**Current Output**
Receiving 5 different items/data instaed of Nested data--> see this [Pycharm Debugger Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw5Nu.png)

Comment: My recent answer for this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76834070/12201407

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
cars[0][car_img_1]:car_img_file1
cars[1][car_img_2]:car_img_file2
```

You can insert it in "bulk-edit" mode.

Comment: In my request data the whole key value is a string( 'cars[0][car_img_1]': ['car_img_file1']), so serializer is not validating the data. Can you please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72664357/send-nested-json-data-with-image-file-from-postman-django-rest-framework) problem. Edited as per your code.

Convert your Image Fields to base64Image and send it through the JSON data.

All you need to do is:

1. go to https://www.base64-image.de/ and convert the image to base64 format. Copy the encoded result.
2. Install `django-extra-fields` package in your project from [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-extra-fields/)
3. In your `serializer_class`, import and change the image field to `Base64ImageField`:

`serializers.py`

```
...
from drf_extra_fields.fields import Base64ImageField
...
```

4. Now, go to your `postman` and send the JSON data like the following. Remember to send that encoded image in your `image` field in JSON.

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars": 
    {
        "car_img_1":"<base64 encoded image>",
        "car_img_2":"<base64 encoded image>",
        "car_img_3":"<base64 encoded image>"
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try in this way (Hint: Watch carefully form-data key names):

[image]

Comment: So, the key point is the indexing syntax for each KVP/data element? - Can you please make that clear, and copy the text of the body into the Answer.