# How to convert raw JSON with nested array field in Postman body into form-data?

Tags: json, rest, post, django-rest-framework

Yesterday I've asked about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60279197/5752558) but got no response maybe because it was too specific related to Django REST Framework. I feel like it's simply the key-value pair problem in form-data I use to post. So I'm going to re-ask the question with simplified content.
What is the form-data format's equivalent for this raw JSON:

```
"markets": [
        {
            "market": 1,
            "name": "White Stone",
            "slabs": [
                1,
                2
            ],
            "thicknesses": [
                1,
                2,
                3
            ],
            "finish_types": [
                1
            ]
        },
        {
            "market": 2,
            "name": "White Marble",
            "slabs": [
                1
            ],
            "thicknesses": [
                1
            ],
            "finish_types": [
                1,
                3,
                6
            ]
        }
]
```

I want to create a new `Product` instance with `markets` field. `markets` is an array and has its own attributes. Some of them are also arrays. I can't send more than 1 `slabs`, `thicknesses`, and `finish_types` each within a single `markets`. `slabs`, `thicknesses`, and `finish_types` are foreign keys.
[image]
When I tried to do the key-value pairs like the image above, the only saved elements are the last one inputed.
Here's the created `markets`:

```
"markets": [
            {
                "id": 65,
                "market": 1,
                "name": "White Stone",
                "slabs": [
                    2
                ],
                "thicknesses": [
                    3
                ],
                "finish_types": [
                    1
                ]
            }
]
```

[image]
And when I tried another key format like this no `slabs` and `thicknesses` will be saved:

```
"markets": [
            {
                "id": 66,
                "market": 1,
                "name": "White Stone",
                "slabs": [],
                "thicknesses": [],
                "finish_types": [
                    1
                ]
            }
]
```

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756688/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-with-the-postman-chrome-extension)  could do a trick for you .  let me know if this solve your problem

Comment: @Rohitpalod Thank you. I actually have visited that question and tried to implement the upvoted answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29425677) answer.

How about you try this format:

```
Key                       Value

markets[0][market]         1
markets[0][name]           white stone
markets[0][slabs][]        2
markets[0][thicknesses][]  3
markets[0][finish_types][] 1
```

And maybe this [Django thread](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1130) might help you.