# Send nested JSON data with image/file from postman: Django REST framework

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, postman, nested-json

I want to POST the following data:

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "user name",
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "phone_number": "01XXXXXXXXX",
        "user_type": "MGR"
    },
    "img": "image_data",
    "manager_brands": [
        2,
        1
    ]
}
```

How can I pass this JSON data through `postman`? Challenges I am facing:

1. This is a nested JSON data
2. I am passing an image with it.

**Note: I wrote the nested serializers to GET/PUT/PATCH/DELETE requests. Everything works fine when I don't send an image (image is optional here)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your Image to base64Image and send it through the JSON data.

All you need to do is:

1. go to https://www.base64-image.de/ and convert the image to base64 format. Copy the encoded result.
2. Install django-extra-fields package in your project from [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-extra-fields/)
3. In your `serializer_class`, change the image field like the following code:

`serializers.py`

```
...
from drf_extra_fields.fields import Base64ImageField
...
 
...
class ProfileSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    img = Base64ImageField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user', 'img', 'manager_brands')
...
```

4. Now, go to your `postman` and send the JSON data like the following. Remember to send that encoded image in your `img` field in JSON.

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "user name",
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "phone_number": "01XXXXXXXXX",
        "user_type": "MGR"
    },
    "img": "<base64 encoded image>",
    "manager_brands": [
        2,
        1
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps :D